# Network Configuration Issue Causing Failure of create-react-app and create-next-app Installations on Regular Network

Tags: next.js, proxy, create-react-app, firewall

Here’s the rundown:

•[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6VPj.jpg)Symptom: Installation of create-react-app and create-next-app via npm fails to complete when I’m connected to my usual network.
•Error: I’ve encountered a range of errors, including “invalid response body,” timeouts, and even cases where the tools abort the installation.
•Network Configuration: I’ve ruled out potential issues with my computer’s stability, and I don’t have access to network or IT support.
•Mobile Data Success: Strangely, when I use my mobile data, the installation process works as expected, indicating that there might be something specific to my regular network causing this trouble.
•Proxy and Firewall: I’ve checked my network settings, and there don’t appear to be any proxy configurations or manual setups. Firewall settings on my computer are also not causing the issue.
•DNS: I suspect there might be DNS issues, but I’m not sure how to confirm this.
•ISP Restrictions: My Internet Service Provider (ISP) could be playing a role, although the specific restrictions, if any, are unknown.